# Getting Error after trying to install npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

i´m new in web development. I´m getting this Error Message after running the command: npm install.

May somebody can help me.

**Message:**

```
PS C:\Users\Giu\node_modules\npm> npm install
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)

> npm@6.4.1 prepare C:\Users\Giu\node_modules\npm
> node bin/npm-cli.js --no-audit --no-timing prune --prefix=. --no-global && rimraf test/*/*/node_modules && make -j4 doc

up to date in 4.661s
Der Befehl "rimraf" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder 
konnte nicht gefunden werden. English: The command "rimraf" is either wrong written or it cant be find.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! npm@6.4.1 prepare: `node bin/npm-cli.js --no-audit --no-timing prune --prefix=. --no-global && rimraf test/*/*/node_modules && make -j4 doc`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the npm@6.4.1 prepare script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Giu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-16T06_40_26_185Z-debug.log
```

**Message end**

Thank you!

Comment: what is that u want to install ?

Comment: I´m not sure. I got a description. 1. Installing node.js and npm 2. Running npm install -g @angular/cli@latest“ 3. npm install 4. ng serve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to install npm download node.js and npm will also be installed [check this link](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm)

then you can install angular cli globally like this `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

then you create angular project using this command `ng new projectName`and also [check this link](https://cli.angular.io/)

then move to project folder `cd projectName`

then install all the project dependencies from package.json using `npm install`

then finally you can run the project and run on browser using `ng serve --open`

Answer (score 1):

In order to install npm download [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) it will be already installed with it.

[CLICK HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm)
To download dependencies from package.json use `npm install` or `npm i`.

To make depencies use initially  type   `npm init`  ,and fill the sufficient details to make your project dependency.